# Proving this inequality for the alternating series of the sequence and functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I've known the properties of the alterating series for the sequences.

Poperty (*)) Let the sequence $x_n$

$S_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^kx_k$. Suppose the $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} S_n(=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^kx_k)$ is convergent to $S$

Then, $\Vert S_n - S \Vert \leq \Vert x_{n+1}\Vert$

---

Let me  expand this idea for the sequence of the functions $f_n$ instead of the $x_n$

My claim (**)) Let the sequence of the functions $f_n : D \to \mathbb{R}$

$S_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^kf_k(x)$. Suppose the $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} S_n(x) (=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^kf_k(x))$ is convergent to $S(x)$ on $D$

Then, $\Vert S_n(x) - S(x) \Vert \leq \Vert f_{n+1}(x)\Vert$ for fixed $\forall x \in D$

I believe that my claim(**) is right. Would you tell me your thought my guess is right or not?

(If it is true, Is proof idea similar with the property(*) ? )

Any help or advice always welcome. Thanks.

Comment: What is $\|.\|$ here ?

Comment: As you are fixing the value of $x$ before any limit, you define SIMPLE limit of a sequence. For being convinced, for x fixed, set $x_k$=$f_k(x)$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, I meant norm in the $ \mathbb{R}$. For instance $\Vert 5 -3 \Vert=2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to impose some monotony on your sequence in order to apply the criteria, it would thus be that $(f_{k})$ is point-wise decreasing.

With this condition, you can just apply (*) point-wise and i believe it may provide interesting uniform bounds if you ask both $f_{k} \forall k$ to be monotonic and $(f_{k}(x))_{k} \forall x$ as well.